# Apache Superset add a textbox entry for ad-hoc dynamic filtering

Tags: filter, textbox, apache-superset, dynamicquery

After searching for several weeks, I cannot seem to pin down how to add an ad-hoc "text entry" filer box.  The goal is to somewhat replace the use of MS Access -- the approach is to create a parameterized SQL query -- and have the parameter be defined through entering text rather than a pull down or predefined filter.

For example, we have 5 million rows, each with a distinct value in column "serial number".  We would like a simple data chart/grid where the user would enter the serial number (or copy/paste from another source) into a free form text box, click a button, and then the data grid would generate based on the parameterized query....NOTE a partial serial number could be used as a wildcard to return a range of products.

Once this is solved we can then proceed with creating dashboards and visualizations of the results, however we are stuck at the basic piece of ad-hoc filtering with a text box?

Researched several weeks, dug into Jinja, found numerous examples utilizing pull-downs or pre-defined filters, however we need an ad-hoc "text entry" box - it could be on a dashboard on on the chart itself.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.